# onLocationChanged being called even when map is just moved

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-maps

```
locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    centerOnMapLocation(location,"Your location");
                }
```

This method `onLocationChanged` should be called only when i **set location** from `extented controls` in emulator i.e. when the user's location is changed.

```
 public void centerOnMapLocation(Location location, String title){
        if(location!=null) {
            LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            mMap.clear();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title(title));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 12));
        }
    }
```

`centerOnMapLocation` moves the camera to the location of the user. When i click **set location** from `extented controls` in emulator, the camera and marker is moved to the new location. That's fine. But after that, when i try to move the within the map, as soon as I stop touching the screen, the camera is moved back to the marker again.

*Basically, when i slide within the map screen to move within the map, as soon as my slide stops(means i stop touching the screen), the camera is moved to the marker again. I want the marker to remain there and I should be able to move within the map as normal*

**Why is it happening when the camera should move only on location change and not map screen change**

Comment: I think you may not realize that, until `removeUpdates()` is called, `onLocationChanged()` will continue to execute generally once every second, even if your location has not actually "changed".

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got a potential fix which i have given as the answer. I tried using `removeUpdates()` but i couldn't insert it correctly into my code as it stopped updating as soon as it is called but i need updates later on again. Please see if my answer looks like a good fix, if yes then do upvote it so that i can understand your approval of it or if you have a better solution then please do give it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line provides location updates to the locationLister.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
```

The third parameter while asking for location updates is the `minimum distance` moved until location is updated. In the above case when `0` is passed, it updates the location continuously and `locationLister` takes it as a new location and `cameraZoom` is updated.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,1,locationListener);
```

To fix this, just change the value of `minimum distance` to some arbitrary value, here `1`. Now until the location is changed, it won't call `centerOnMapLocation`.

Comment: Yes, this is a fine solution, and if it works for you, then that's all you need. However, you should be aware of some potential edge cases: Location/GPS has limited accuracy, and it has _noise_. The detected location will sometimes move around by many _meters_, _even if you are not physically moving_. Some devices will be able to successfully filter out most of that noise; others will not. Your selected min distance is 1 _meter_, which is not particularly large, so if a user takes a step or two while dragging the map, you may find their position has been reset.

Comment: Yes and I'm aware of that. While release, those parameters will be changed accordingly. This case was while testing. I kept the minTime and minDistance as 0. The thing is that while testing on emulator, device doesn't move even a bit and earlier it allowed to move inside the map. but seems like after some update now, even if location isn't changed, if minDistance is 0, it calls the function continuously.